# Is there a way to execute html inside of a template variable that is a table?

Tags: python, html, css, django, forms

I am creating a website using Django and I have taken a pandas dataframe and stored it as a template variable and passed it to the render request. I would like to make some columns form elements but have been unsuccessful into how to do that.

I have already tried applying the function to the pandas dataframe in order to add the proper HTML to each element in the column. However, the HTML itself shows up on the actual site.

Here is my python code:

```
def optimizer(request):
    df = Optimizer.get_daily_roster('E:\website\optimizer\Predictions.csv')
    df = df.drop(columns=['Name + ID', 'Game Info', 'Unnamed: 0', 'Unnamed: 0.1', 'name'])
    df = df.rename(columns={'TeamAbbrev': 'Team', 'AvgPointsPerGame': 'Predicted FP'})
    df['Predicted FP'] = df['Predicted FP'].apply(lambda x: round(float(x), 2))
    df['Predicted FP'] = df['Predicted FP'].apply(lambda x: "<input type='text' value=" + str(x) + ">")
    df['Min Exposure'] = 0
    df['Max Exposure'] = 1
    # cols_to_values = df.to_dict(orient='list')
    # cols_to_values = {x.translate({32: None}): y
    #                 for x, y in cols_to_values.items()}
    html_table = df.to_html(index=False, justify='left',
                            classes=[
                                'table table-bordered table-striped table-hover table-responsive table-sm, container-fluid'])
    return render(request, 'optimizer/optimizer.html', {'player_table': html_table})
```

And here is my HTML:

```
{% extends "optimizer/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<h1>Optimizer</h1>
<form method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="Generate Lineups">
    <div class="table-responsive">
        {{ player_table |safe }}
    </div>
</form>
{% endblock content %}
```

I am getting table data fields that say the entire HTML string. For example, one says `"<input type='text' value=55.95>"`. It should just say 55.95 and be an editable form field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `pandas.DataFrame.to_html()` will escape unsafe characters.

You can change that behavior by passing `escape=False` (see [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html#pandas-dataframe-to-html)).

Note that this makes your application potentially vulnerable to Cross-Site Scripting Attacks and you will not benefit from Django's form validation facilities